# Switching row header and column header in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a .csv file that has data something like this:

```
#file...out/houses.csv
#data...sun may 1 11:20:43 2011
#user...abs12
#host...(null)
#group...class=house
#property..change_per_hour
#limit...0
#interval..10000000
#timestamp,house_0,house_1,house_2,house_3,.....,house_1000
2010-07-01 00:00:00 EDT,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,........,9.72
2010-07-01 01:00:00 EDT,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,........,19.72
2010-07-01 02:00:00 EDT,3.2,3.3,3.4,3.5,........,29.72
2010-07-01 05:00:00 EDT,5.2,5.3,5.4,5.5,........,59.72
2010-07-01 06:00:00 EDT,6.2,,6.4,,..............,
...
```

I want to convert this and save to a new .csv and the data should look like:

```
#file...out/houses.csv
#data...sun may 1 11:20:43 2011
#user...abs12
#host...(null)
#group...class=house
#property..change_per_hour
#limit...0
#interval..10000000
#EntityName,2010-07-01 00:00:00 EDT,2010-07-01 01:00:00 EDT,2010-07-01 02:00:00 EDT,2010-07-01 05:00:00 EDT,2010-07-01 06:00:00 EDT
house_0,1.2,2.2,3.2,5.2,6.2,...
house_1,1.3,2.3,3.3,5.3,,...
house_2,1.4,2.4,3.4,5.4,6.4,...
house_3,1.5,2.5,3.5,5.5,,...
...
house_1000,9.72,19.72,29.72,59.72,
```

I tried to use pandas: convert to a dictionary that looks like `dtDict={'house_0':{'datetimestamp_1':'value_1','datetimestamp_2':'value_2'...}...}`but I am not able to convert to a dictionary and use panda's `DataFrame` such as `pandas.DataFrame(dtDict)` to do that conversion. I dont have to use pandas (can you anything in python) but thought pandas is good for csv manipulation. any help?

Comment: I wonder if you could load it into an array with something like np.loadtxt, transpose it (or some of it) and write it back to the csv file. Haven't really thought it through.

Comment: @Ogaday I thought of that but couldnt get it to working and recalled something I used `pandas` for in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is in a pandas dataframe already, this works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[[1, 3], [2, 5]],
    index=[0, 1],
    columns=['a', 'b']
)
```

Output:

```
>>>print(df)
      a  b
   0  1  3
   1  2  5
```

Then, transpose the dataframe:

```
>>>print(df.transpose())
      0  1
   a  1  2
   b  3  5
```

Comment: here you are hardcoding `index`. In my case, the original data is in `test.csv` file. can you please give an example for this scenario?

Comment: @NikhilGupta I honestly do not know what you mean. My posted dataframe is an example. Do you need help on how to read your csv into a pandas dataframe?

Comment: I managed to read-in and convert the content of my .csv file into something that looks like `df` in your example but its not a square frame. Any suggestions on how to do the same if its not a square frame? (FYI, I tried with a csv file with square frame and incorporated your example and it works)

Comment: @NikhilGupta I am so sorry! From the way you phrased you question, I assumed you wanted to _literally_ switch your index and columns. That is indeed only possible when the frame is square, but that is not your desired output. What you need is a simple transpose! I'll update my answer, please give me a minute.

Comment: totally alright. It also looks like the method you suggested doesn't arrange the data appropriately. It shifts the row and column header but not the data.

Comment: @NikhilGupta it does so because that'd be a literal switch of the index and columns. I must admit, your question struck me as odd, but now that I understand you simply want to transpose the data, that's incredibly easy to do!

Comment: + This works perfect. I did not know about `transpose`. I am assuming I can simply use python's csv-methods to write the new `df` to a .csv file, right?

Comment: @NikhilGupta you might want to look into [DataFrame.to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)!